# Using the eval function

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to use the `eval` function in the following scenario:

- Assuming I have two expressions :

  1. A ← A * 3
  2. A ← 3 * A

  In the second half of these expressions I'd like to get True because they are equal.
- Assuming I have other two expressions :

  1. A ← A % 3
  2. A ← 3 % A

In the second half of these expressions I'd like to get False because they are not equal.

I've done, with Stack Overflow's help, a large program, the part that I'm curious about is:

```
import sys
def main() :

opt1_raw = "A ← T + 2"
opt2_raw = "A ← 2 + T"

opt1 = opt1_raw.split("←")[1]
opt2 = opt2_raw.split("←")[1] 


for char in opt1 : 
    if char.isdigit() or char.isalpha() :        
        ascii_exp1 = ''.join(str(ord(char)))
    x = eval(ascii_exp1)
```

The same goes for opt2 with y variable, then I compare two variables, x and y.

At the end of my program I have these lines :

```
if  ( x != y ) :
    sys.exit()
else :
    print("Equals")
```

The result is not "Equals" for this example.

Why doesn't it work?

Comment: What doesn't work?

Comment: Comparing x and y I'm getting wrong results.

Comment: Would you care to share, the expected and actual results? Actually the whole code involved for this question, and its output (as described by [\[SO\]: mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve))

Comment: Hint: Look at the value of `ascii_exp1` just before you run the eval. _(Edit: Actually, I'm not at all sure what you're trying to do with that whole `for` block. Take some time to step through it manually and see what it's actually doing.)_

Comment: Thanks, I did that but x holds the last data only, even if I put it outside 'for in'.

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is that you have `ascii_exp1 = ''.join(str(ord(char)))` rather than `ascii_exp1 += ''.join(str(ord(char)))`, that is, you are replacing the entire thing rather than appending to it. Therefore, you're just comparing the values of the last character in each string, which aren't equal. (Note that you'll need to declare ascii_exp1 above the loop in order to append to it inside the loop.)

`str(ord(char))` is also a really weird thing to do to digits, your 2s become '50's instead of '2's as you might have desired. I think you should just leave out the `char.isdigit()` part and leave those as is, eval will read them correctly.

EDIT in response to comment: Ah, yeah, you were also missing the else case. Here's the fixed code:

```
opt1_raw = "A ^ T + 2"
opt2_raw = "A ^ 2 + T"

opt1 = opt1_raw.split("^")[1]
opt2 = opt2_raw.split("^")[1] 

ascii_exp1 = ''
for char in opt1 : 
    if char.isdigit() or char.isalpha() :        
        ascii_exp1 += ''.join(str(ord(char)))
    else:
        ascii_exp1 += char
x = eval(ascii_exp1)

ascii_exp2 = ''
for char in opt2 : 
    if char.isdigit() or char.isalpha() :        
        ascii_exp2 += ''.join(str(ord(char)))
    else:
        ascii_exp2 += char

y = eval(ascii_exp2)

print x == y
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried it, no luck.
What is the equivalent, **in multi-lines**, of the code below ?
`ascii_exp = ''.join([str(ord(char)) if char.isdigit() or char.isalpha() else char for char in a])`
I started with "for char in a".
Actually this is what I'm looking for to solve this issue, because with the above one-line code it works fine.

Comment: Thank you, it works, I didn't know how to convert the one-line code to multilines ( I have some other code also inside, that's why I prefer that code ). Because I am a new member I think I cannot accept it as solution yet. (It recorder but will not change the score)